# Cannot run docker container in windows server 2019

Tags: windows, docker

Cannot run docker container in windows server 2019 vmware. It was error response from daemon

```
docker container run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 hostname

docker: Error response from daemon: container bb81979fe2974f59031e56e062f1b08f1ad6fdaa57ec57965c316563f384da59 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: context deadline exceeded.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it with Hyper-V?

```
docker run -it --isolation=hyperv mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
```

If it works you can create or edit the config file:
*C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json*

Add:

```
{
    "exec-opts": ["isolation=hyperv"]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Sure. If you are using something that does not require windows container. You can run a container on linux. I would install an instance of ubuntu or centos on vmware install docker and work with it there.

Download centos
https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/downloading/

Install docker
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

A side not though this is not really production grade orchestration. You may want to look at docker swarm / kubernetes / openshift for prod workloads.

Comment: linux no issue but issue on windows